# asp.net core web app how to route page requests for index.html and default.html to razor page index.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I'm converting a static web site to an asp.net core web app. I've noticed that the index.cshtml razor page is served as /index and /index.html gives a 404 not found, unless added as a static page.

Problem is external sites have indexed direct links to /index.html, /default.html and other pages.

Curious if asp.net core has a better way than adding the static pages with redirect. Like a reverse UseDefaultFiles()

Thanks.

Reasearch has turned up nothing. Lots of results to route default requests to static pages. But I want the reverse. Static page requests to razor pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand your question, You want to access razor page in the route of `/pagename.cshtml` and don't want to add static page. You can specify the route name as you want via Route Templates.

For Example, The default code in Privacy is:

```
@page 
@model PrivacyModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Privacy Policy";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<p>Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
```

If you want to access this page as `/privacy.html` instead of `/privacy`, You can specify route after `@page`.

Change code like:

```
@page "/privacy.html"
@model PrivacyModel
//.......
```

Now i can access privacy page in the route of `/privacy.html`.

Demo:

[image]

Comment: That works. Thanks. Would be great if it would serve up multiple, such as /index.html, /default.html ...

Comment: Is there any config option to ignore .html part of the route? I.E. both `/privacy` abd `/privacy.html` should serve RazorPage Privacy.cshtml, and the same should be true for any other page?

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar issue, and found this to be a solution in my case:

When adding razor pages to the application, you can add additional routing conventions such as

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Index", "index.html");
});
```

That way, both `/index` and `/index.html` route to the same page.

Not sure if there are some nasty side-effects to this method, if so feel free to comment and share the knowledge.

Comment: Is there any way to do it by convention for all RazorPages?